# XAMPP: Problem Php-intl installation on OSX

Tags: php, macos, xampp, php-7.4

I have problem when I try install intl on OSX using XAMPP

`which php`
**/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php**

`php -v` **7.4.11**

My steps

1. run `sudo pecl install intl`
2. In this question `Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :`  I put `/usr/local but` I try and with empty.

And I get this error:

```
running: make
/bin/ksh /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootrPfAYl/intl-3.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -Wno-write-strings -I. -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootrPfAYl/intl-3.0.0/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootrPfAYl/intl-3.0.0/main -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c -o php_intl.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -Wno-write-strings -I. -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootrPfAYl/intl-3.0.0/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootrPfAYl/intl-3.0.0/main -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_intl.o
In file included from /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ubrk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:192: php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Ech... I am stuck here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with xampp and it was never easy to install any php extension in xampp on mac. There is always some issue with either brew package or the extension. So I moved to MAMP. It's really easy to install extensions in MAMP.

P.S. MAMP comes with intl extension already enabled.